# Elasticsearch Unreachable - Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm using the ELK Stack with Docker.
Everything worked fine, except the day when my server ran out of space because I didn't manage well the lifetime of my data.
I had to remove and build again my Docker containers.
My problem is that I don't know if it's directly related or not, but I have errors when I try to start Kibana and Logstash. They can't reach Elasticsearch service.

**Errors:**

```
logstash_1       | [2019-08-09T08:01:50,916][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ConnectTimeout] connect timed out"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-09T08:06:30Z","tags":["license","warning","xpack"],"pid":1,"message":"License information from the X-Pack plugin could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms"}
```

However, Elasticsearch seems to be up:

```
curl -GET 'http://elastic:XXXXX@localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "4bc961f74ca3",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "N1HmOLw4Q3umF8vMPiVQbA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.2.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "fe6cb20",
    "build_date" : "2019-07-24T17:58:29.979462Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Here my config (come from https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk):

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'

services:

          elasticsearch:
            build:
              context: elasticsearch/
              args:
                ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
            volumes:
              - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
            ports:
              - "9200:9200"
              - "9300:9300"
            environment:
              ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
              ELASTIC_PASSWORD: XXXXX
            networks:
              - elk

          logstash:
            build:
              context: logstash/
              args:
                ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
            volumes:
              - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
              - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro
            ports:
              - "5000:5000"
              - "9600:9600"
            environment:
              LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
            networks:
              - elk
            depends_on:
              - elasticsearch

      kibana:
        build:
          context: kibana/
          args:
            ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
        volumes:
          - ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro
        ports:
          - "5601:5601"
        networks:
          - elk
        depends_on:
          - elasticsearch

networks:

  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

**elasticsearch.yml:**

```
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0

discovery.type: single-node

xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true
```

**kibana.yml:**

```
server.name: kibana
server.host: "0"
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]
xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true

elasticsearch.username: elastic
elasticsearch.password: XXXXX
```

**logstash.yml:**

```
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: elastic
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: XXXXX
```

I'm pretty sure it's a basic mistake I made, but I checked everything and I don't see where it comes from.
It's strange because I didn't change any configuration since when it worked. I even put back the default setting from the git repository, and I have the same error.
Maybe when my server ran out of memory, it changes some settings on the server that I'm not aware? (in this case, it's not related to Elastic but I don't know where to search).

Comment: You have a small typo in your docker-compose.yml file: `networiks` instead of `networks`. Could this be the culprit?

Comment: Ohh I didn't see it. Sadly, I made it by copy/paste, I don't know how. Thank you anyway, I hoped it was the mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to establish that a new build is working, I went ahead and cloned the repo you referenced and was able to stand up the working (empty) ELK stack - so there shouldn't be an issue with the source material.

Looking at your build date for Elasticsearch, are you trying to connect a new docker-elk to an existing, dockerized, ES? If so, did you verify the network configuration for the new Logstash and Kibana matches the network / name / etc. for the pre-existing dockerized ES?

For testing: I've noticed that some people have had issues with configuring XPACK Monitoring in particular for this scenario. As a test case, can you try a deploy with XPACK Monitoring disabled to see if the issue is related to that piece of your configuration? To disable, just set `xpack.monitoring.enabled: false` and comment out the other `xpack.monitoring` lines.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is this build date. It is true that after my first docker-elk stopped to work, I cloned the git repository in an other folder. I wanted to try on a simple config. So I did my test on the new docker-elk, but I don't think I'm trying to connect an existing, dockerized, ES? I think I reset everything with 'docker system prune -a', 'docker-compose build', and 'docker-compose up'. To be sure, I try before rebuild to change the name of the network and docker-cluster, and it seems to be all on the same. Maybe I'm wrong? How do I verify properly?

Comment: Yes, I saw that too on other posts. I tried to disable Xpack monitoring but it still doesn't work :/